# Proving an equation for a set of ordered triples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am studying for an exam and I would appreciate some help with this question:

Let S be the set of ordered triples of integers that are defined in the following way:

- (66, 55, 1331) is an element of S.
- If (a, b, c) is an element of S then (a+7, b+5, 14a-10b+c+24) is an element of S

Prove that for every element (a, b, c) in S:

a^2 - b^2 = c

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try induction.

The first part of an inductive proof of this is almost trivial: simply verify that $66^2-55^2=1331$.

For the second part, you need to assume that $a^2-b^2 = c$, and then prove that $(a+7)^2 - (b+5)^2 = 14a-10b+c+24$. This amounts to messy algebra.

Since every element of $S$ is generated by that operation, this will conclude the proof.